# How to export Postgres SQL statement as XML dump

Tags: xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to export an SQL statement in PostgresSQL to XML?

In MySQL I am using this statement:

```
mysql -u root -p --xml -e "SELECT * FROM new.table" > path/table.xml
```

But how shall I do it in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this on the SQL level using functions like `xmlforest` and `xmlagg`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-PRODUCING-XML) for details.